# Android No such table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Tengo una APP en la cual estaba trabajando con una tabla sqlite, todo bien, ahora le agrego otra, pongo el código pero no se genera. En el DBHelper agregue en el onCreate la sentencia para crear la tabla con db.execSQL pero cuando voy a la actividad me tira el error que no existe la tabla

```
public class LecturasDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Lecturas.db";

public LecturasDBHelper(Context context, String nombre, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Columnas.TABLE_NAME + " (" etc..
```

y en la  actividad

```
LecturasDBHelper reclamobd = new LecturasDBHelper(MapsActivity.this, Constantes.DB_NAME, null, Constantes.VERSION);
SQLiteDatabase db = reclamobd.getWritableDatabase();

String selectQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM " + ReclamosColumnas.ColumnasReclamos.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ReclamosColumnas.ColumnasReclamos.COLUMN_NAME_TERMINADO + " = 1";
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
```

Este mismo código me funciona bien con la tabla anterior, pero ahora no genera la nueva tabla dentro de la misma DB, me está faltando algo?

Comment: Ya esta resuelto, solo era cuestión de reinstalar la APP, borrarla del dispositivo y volver a instalarla

Comment: No creo que esa sea la solución, public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; sirve para eso, por si haces algún, cambio en la base de dato, aun cuando la app ya la este en el marquet, si agregas o borras tablas a la base de datos, debes cambiarla, la app al ver que la versión de la base de datos es diferente se actualiza.

Comment: No creo que esa sea la solución, public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; sirve para eso, por si haces algún, cambio en la base de dato, aun cuando la app ya la este en el marquet, si agregas o borras tablas a la base de datos, debes cambiarla, la app al ver que la versión de la base de datos es diferente se actualiza.

Comment: @desarrollosTELLO revisa mi respuesta, recuerda que si quieres crear más tablas en tu base de datos, puedes realizarlo dentro de  onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) y para una aplicación en Google Play Store no será solución reinstalar la aplicación, eso no lo realizarán los usuarios, saludos.

Comment: @desarrollosTELLO por cierto acabo de ver que ninguna de las preguntas que has realizado tienen una respuesta marcada como correcta, ¿no te ayudo ninguna respuesta de los usuarios de la comunidad Stackoverflow en español?, revisa [tour].

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a el error:

```
no such table: Tabla (code 1): ....
```

indicas este problema:

> Este mismo código me funciona bien con la tabla anterior, pero ahora
>   no genera la nueva tabla dentro de la misma DB

Lo que deseas realizar es un cambio en la estructura de los elementos de la base de datos, en este caso la tabla, esta no se creara nuevamente a menos que realices alguno de estos 3 puntos, cualquiera obligara a llamar nuevamente el método `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` y creara la tabla:

**1)** Puedes ir a aplicaciones y eliminar el caché de tu aplicación.

**2)** Eliminar la aplicación e instalar nuevamente.

**3)** Cambia la versión de la base de datos, esto lo realizarías en la clase que extiende de [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int))

```
public class LecturasDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3; //Originalmente era 2
...
...
```

> **Importante:** El punto **1)** y **2)** lo puedes realizar mientras pruebas pero en
>   producción esto no se podrá realizar, para esto se debe realizar el punto **3)** ya que cuando subes una
>   actualización de tu aplicación que implica un cambio en el contenido
>   de la base de datos o la estructura de las tablas debes aumentar el
>   valor de la versión de la base de datos.